# Sorting a key,value list in R by value

Tags: r, key-value

Given a list animals, call it m, which contains

```
$bob
[1] 3

$ryan
[1] 4

$dan
[1] 1
```

How can I sort this guy by the numerical value? 
Basically I'd like to see my code look like this

```
m=sort(m,sortbynumber)


$ryan
[1] 4

$bob
[1] 3

$dan
[1] 1
```

I can't figure this out unfortunately. Seems like a simple solution.

Comment: FYI, atomic vectors can have names, too.

Comment: Yeah, if each element of the list is a single value, it probably makes sense to simply store in a vanilla vector as Matthew suggested. `mm <- unlist(m); sort(m,decreasing=TRUE)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try `order`

```
m[order(-unlist(m))]
#$ryan
#[1] 4

#$bob
#[1] 3

#$dan
#[1] 1
```

Or a slightly more efficient option would be to use `decreasing=TRUE` argument of `order` (from @nicola's comments)

```
m[order(unlist(m), decreasing=TRUE)]
```

Comment: I guess that `order(unlist(m),decreasing=TRUE)` might be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Of course the masters would have a solution in t-minus 10 seconds. Thanks

Comment: Just curious, when you unlist I see I get the three elements in a table format. If I look at the unlist(m)[1] i get first element and so on. How can i go deeper. I mean extract specifically the first field of the first element or the second element of the first field.

Comment: It's not a table, it's a named vector. See here for instance: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector/named-vector-members You can extract the names with the `names` function. Try `names(unlist(m))`.

Comment: How would one get the numerical values?

Comment: Just use `unname(unlist(m))`

Answer (score 1):

here is the optimized solution

```
library(hashmap)

a1<-hashmap("hello",1)
a1$insert("hello1",4)
a1$insert("hello2",2)
a1$insert("hello3",3)


sort(a1$data(),decreasing = TRUE)
```

#OUTPUT

```
hello1 hello3 hello2  hello 
   4      3      2      1
```